# Logout user and delete cookies from the client side?

Tags: javascript, cookies, logout

I'd like to be able to logout the user. I can do this by calling wp_logout() on the server but if the user drops connection is there a way to log them out?

The wp_logout() method clears the cookies. Is there a way to do this on the client? Maybe like a clear all cookies (logout) for this domain or path.

**More Info:**
For example, say they are at school or at the library on a public computer and the connection drops (which happens a lot).

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: @SebastianScholle I think the answer below might have solved it but I can't recall now and I'm not on the project anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to combine the solutions in these answers to achieve what you are looking for. Keep checking and if the internet connection drops, clear the cookies.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426851/quickest-way-to-check-internet-connectivity-in-js
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript